# Browser superimposed on Browser

Tags: html, browser

Is there any standard way (or library) to superimpose one HTML5 browser window on top of another?

One purpose of this would be when upgrading the code of any existing HTML frontend while keeping the appearance exactly like the old one: you could load up the old frontend and then load up your in-progress new frontend "on top" of it and either make one of them translucent like tracing paper, or toggle one of them on and off.

Doing this with static HTML/CSS and no javascript is not too hard, but I have no idea how you would do it while maintaining all the cookies, localstorage, using javascript, etc for each "version".

I'm really looking for a way to do this in just HTML/CSS/JS (inside one actual browser), but if it can't be done, I'm interested in browser extensions that can do this.

Comment: Look into double buffering, though I seriously doubt you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered loading the new frontend in an iframe? You might have to attach version numbers to your cookies and localstorage, depends on the exact implementation.